# Transfer Google Chrome profiles from Ubuntu to windows

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, transfer

I have to use both Ubuntu and Windows. Consequently I also need to use Google Chrome on both. I have tried to transfer my chrome profiles FROM Ubuntu 20.04 to Windows 10 unsuccessfully despite scrutinizing the different guidance found on blogs and Google chrome  support.

So far, here is what I have done:

- copy from Ubuntu the chrome profiles located in : `~/.config/google-chrome` to a pen drive
- Deleting profiles in `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` on the drive of the windows target pc
- Finally copy from pen drive to `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`.

It just does not work.
I wonder if transferring chrome profiles from ubuntu to windows is even possible.

*Please note that some of the chrome profiles are linked to NO google account so the google sync is not an option.
Indeed, it seems the sync method does not allow to keep the chrome settings which I want to do (such as the name of the chrome window and other chrome settings like pinned tabs)*

Is there a way to achieve a successful transfer of chrome profiles FROM ubuntu TO windows?

Thank you all.

Comment: Does google-chrome run as "snap" on Ubuntu, or is it installed from native "deb" ?

Comment: @kanehekili via snap

Comment: That's technically 50% Windows related ... However, it seems your target "copy to" path on Windows is one folder short according to this: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#windows i.e. `...\Google\Chrome\User Data`

Comment: @Raffa you are correct twice. I correct my post. I can confirm I pointed on the right folders (ubuntu and Windows) when trying to fo that. I also appreciate this is more a google chrome related issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Chromium(or google-chrome)  snap will find an existing profile in ~/.config/chromium, and will copy it over to

> ~/snap/chromium/current/.config

or

> ~/snap/google-chrome/current/.config

on its first run. So your actual data should be in the snap folder and not in `~/.config'`. You can verify this by checking the timestamps in both `.config` subfolders

Comment: Thanks of your answer. What does it have to do with transfering chrome profiles to windows? Genuine question. Also I have checked `snap list` and I was wrong Google chrome is not installed via snap , probably with a .deb file. Sorry for this mistake.

Comment: That the location of your profiles that you want to copy is in another place than you mentioned. Chrome and chromium are the same, but I'll update my answer